# Converting this notification message that can be just collapsed into one that can be collapsed and expanded

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQuery code to show a notification at the top the page with a sliding animation:

```
// Notification
$j("#notification").animate({
    height: "21px",
    opacity: 1,
    'padding-top': "8px"
}, 800 );

$j("#close-button").click( function() {
    $j("#notification").animate({
      height: "0px",
      opacity: 0,
      'padding-top': "0px"
    }, 800 );
});
```

Live example:

http://www.taiwantalk.org/

Right now, you can just collapse the notification. But I would like to add a button that enables you to expand it and collapse it.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) would seem to be very convenient here.

#### EDIT : Using `.slideToggle()`

Provided that you've got an HTML element like the following:

```
<style type='text/css'>
#foo { height:100px; padding:10px; background-color:#fafafa; }
</style>
<div id='foo'>Ohayou Sekai!</div>
<button id='bar'>SLIDE!</button>
```

You can make it slide out of sight / slide back in using `.slideToggle()`. For example, we're going to hook that in to a button's `click` event:

```
$('#bar').click(function() {
    $('#foo').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

It automatically decides whether or not it should slide to hide or slide to show for you.

[Here's a demo as well](http://jsfiddle.net/DDsXQ/).

Comment: sorry, I've never used that before. Could you give me an example of the code?

Comment: @alexchenco ~ Updated for you.